# Write long value as double on a file in c++

Tags: c++, types, casting, type-conversion

I am using `std::map<string, long>M`. I need to write the long value on a file but as double. For example, if the `long` value is 0 then I need to write 0.0 on file and 10 as 10.0, exactly in that format. I tried casting `double` but when written on file, it shows as an integer (long). Even I tried to used `std::map<string, double>M` but still while printed, the value is written as integer (long) value not as decimals. How can I write `long` values in `double` as mentioned format?

For the following code:

```
ofstream write;
write.open("3-mer.txt", std::ofstream::out);
std::map<string, long>::iterator it;
it = C.find(threes);
if(it != C.end())
{
    write << std::setprecision(1) << (double)(it->second) << " ";
}
```

I am getting output like the following:

```
1 1e+01 0 2e+01 0 1e+01 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 0 0 0 
2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1e+01 0 0 8 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 2e+01 0 0 0 0 0 0 2e+01 2e+01 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Did you try `std::setprecision()` before writing to file?

Comment: yes I did.. didn't work either

Comment: Post a [MCVE] of what you actually have.

Comment: You're going to have to add a sample bit of code here. Nobody has any idea what you're doing. `setprecision` should work, and if it doesn't you're probably doing something odd .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing yourself.

You don't need a `double`, you need a decimal.  Totally different thing.

Terrible, but working idea, print the `.0` manually:

```
write << (it->second) << ".0 " ;
```

Comment: Actually the output printed in the file is going to be input of another file where the input must be taken as doubles. If I do it this way, isn't it becoming a string?

Comment: You have to decide if the output is text, or a binary file.  If its binary, you're going to have to go through a totally different process to write it.